# How to obtain a Microsoft Certificate (*.cer & .pfx)?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, cer

In order to upload a service on Microsoft Azure Cloud there is a cer file required, to proof the identity. How can I purchase one for my company?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not buy the .cer certificate, just create it: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/cloud-services-certs-create/

Do you need to use the .pfx certificate as well? I have not yet had to use one of those in my Azure apps but the linked page talks about how to use one.